# Set Interval and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, setinterval

my jquery isn't auto refreshing, with the following code, is there any issue with it(seeBelow). I basically want it to check if any new bids have been placed and then update the html :)

EDIT:

```
function checkBids(){
    var id = $('div.auction').attr('id') 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/tinybid/index.php/auction/auctiondata',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
                if (json['i'] = 'product'+id) {
                    $('li.user').html(json['u']);
                    $('li.curPrice').html(json['p']);
                }
            }
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(checkBids, 1000);
});
```

Here is the auctiondata -

```
function auctiondata(){
        $this->load->model('Auction_model', 'Auction');
        $this->load->model('Bid_model', 'Bid');
        $this->load->model('Customer_model', 'Customer');

        $auctions = $this->Auction->getAllAuctions();

        foreach ($auctions as $auction){
            $lastBid = $this->Bid->getLastBid($auction['auction_id']);
            $user = $this->Customer->getUserById($lastBid['user_id']);
            $bid = strtotime($lastBid['end_time']);

            $json[] = array(
                'i' => $auction['auction_id'],
                't' => $bid,
                'p' => '&pound; '.$auction['current_price'],
                'u' => $user['username']
            );  
        }

        echo json_encode($json);
    }
```

EDIT 15:13 15/12/2011:
here is the json output from the data :
[{"i":"1","t":1323961871,"p":"£ 0.23","u":"joe2011uk"},{"i":"2","t":1323957557,"p":"£ 0.03","u":"joe2011uk"}]

the page is displaying the previous bid for i:1,

still not updating

Can anyone help, thanks for your time

Kerry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `()` from the way you pass `checkBids` to `setInterval`.

By suffixing the function name with `()`, you are *calling* `checkBids`, and passing the return value to `setInterval` - which in your case in `null` (because you don't call `return` at any point). This will result in `checkBids` being called once, and only once.

A function is like any other "value" (object) in Javascript - you pass it around just as you would a string or a number.

You *can* do what @Shvelo suggested and use the syntax you used, but wrap it in quotes to turn it into a string. However, you **should not** do this - this effectively means that `setInterval` calls `eval()` on the string you passed, which is inefficient and prone to errors. [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) will not like you for doing it either.

Change

```
setInterval(checkBids(), 1000);
```

to

```
setInterval(checkBids, 1000);
```

Also, swap your two code segments around - you should define your function before you try and use it anywhere.

**EDIT**

After the long discussion below, I *think* you want to do this in you success function.

If you give your individual auction `<div>`s IDs of `auction<id>`, where `<id>` is the numeric ID returned in `json['i']`, then do this:

```
 // ...
 success: function(json) {
   for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
     $('#auction'+json[i]['i']+' li.user').html(json[i]['u']);
     $('#auction'+json[i]['i']+' li.curPrice').html(json[i]['p']);
   }
 }
 // ...
```

I *think* it should do what you want.

Comment: ok I have got this working down to the if statement lol grrrr!

Comment: `I have got this working down to the if statement` - do you mean `it is now working because the if statement was wrong` or `I have this working until I reach the if statement`? Essentially, is it fixed? :)

Comment: sorry for being unclear dave I have the code working until the if statement is reached ive tried to alert(id) now when i alert(json['i']) it is alerting undefined but when u run the url it says that i does have a value. could the problem be that i need to loop through the json variable?

Comment: Oh yeh, of course, that is the problem - your JSON is an array of multiple objects, but you are referencing it as it were only one object. Since you only seem to want the most recent bid of a specific auction (?), you might be better rewriting so that you pass the auction ID to PHP in the URL, and the PHP only returns the data for the one auction you are interested in. But working with your existing PHP you should... (continued in next comment)

Comment: can i just say if i loop through the array that is fine but see the var id how can i get that to display the correct div id for the specific json object does that make sense

Comment: ...change your success function to: `for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { if (i == json[i]['i']) { // Do stuff here } }`. Something else I just noticed is that in your `if` as it is above, `=` should be `==`, and even if it was one object `json['i']` would never be equal to `'product'+id` because `json['i']` is an integer and `'product'+id` is a string, prefixed with the word "product"

Comment: Oh no, hang on, that's not right... Sorry, what value do you expect `id` to have? Is it just an integer or something else?

Comment: i have removed the prefix product now id is just a int and has a class of auction now at present there is two divs with #1 & #2 both with .auction how can i reference these in that foreach so the correct json is in the right place

Comment: See edit above. If that doesn't work, I may need to see some HTML.

Comment: Woohoo finally lol, thank you ever so much dave for all your help today as you can see javascript isnt my strong point lol, thanks with all my heart if there is anything i can do for you just ask :) can i just ask see when the $(document wasnt working and we changed ti to javascript and it started working why could that of been as jquery library is loaded :) x

Comment: I have honestly got no idea whatsoever why that didn't work. jQuery is not my strong point - I tend to use straight Javascript - so I just suggested that as something I knew should work. Does jQ have a `$(document).load()` or `$(window).load()`? If it does, I would have thought that is fired using `window.onload`, and it would be (arguably) the better way to do it. Maybe it doesn't like running setInterval before the DOM is ready? Who knows... On a sidenote, your `id` variable is now redundant and can be removed.

Comment: great dave, thanks soooo much for everything there is a $(window).load() function so maybe using that would work

Answer (score 0):

You're using `checkBids()`'s `return` value, which is actually `null`
use `setInterval('checkBids()', 1000);`

Comment: the check bid shouldnt be returning null neither it should is sumthing wrong with ma php that a havent noticed :S updated with the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

the

```
 setInterval(checkBids(), 1000);
```

would be better with either quotes (ugh, uses eval) or wrapped:

```
setInterval(function(){checkBids();}, 1000);
```

slight fix to your syntax:

```
if (json['i'] = 'product'+id) {
```

should be

```
if (json['i'] == 'product'+id) {
```

or

```
if (json['i'] === 'product'+id) {
```

Comment: Note that the `if` syntax probably has more to do with the use of the returned values rather than the execution cycling - which involves the `setInterval`